# The command /bin/sh -c gradle run returned a non-zero code: 127

Tags: docker

Following is my `dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7-jdk
ENV APP_HOME=/root/dev/beverage
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . $APP_HOME
RUN gradle run
CMD ["java", "-jar", "build/libs/beverage-all.jar"]
```

When I try on the docker following command `docker build -t beverage .` it throws the following error

```
/bin/sh: 1: gradle: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c gradle run' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I have seen a similar question on the website but being a beginner it's hard for me to understand.

Comment: That `openjdk` image probably only contains the JVM/JDK, but not any accessory tools like Maven, Gradle, _etc._  You'd have to manually install those in your Dockerfile.

Comment: @DavidMaze Please let me know how can I do that? any tutorial that I might need to refer to? Thanks

Comment: Either look for openjdk image which also contains Maven, or install Maven just like you wound on your local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @David, you need to install Gradle, the below Dockerfile will build against `gradle-6.5.1`.

You can find the required version [gradle distributions](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
ENV APP_HOME=/root/dev/beverage
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . $APP_HOME
WORKDIR /app
RUN curl -L https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip -o gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip
RUN unzip gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip
ENV GRADLE_HOME=/app/gradle-6.5.1
ENV PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
RUN gradle --version
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
CMD ["java", "-jar", "build/libs/beverage-all.jar"]
```

Comment: your solution fixed my problem, however through it when I run my container it exits automatically instantly. what should I do?

Comment: Might be issue with the Java application because it the cmd the keep the container running